# Is it possible to create a sub-script?

Tags: batch-file, subprocess

Something like: (This is an example)

```
call :sub
echo comes first.
goto end
:sub (
echo This part
)
:end
```

Maybe? If so, what would be the proper way to format it?
I'm aware that I can just call .bat files, but I'd prefer to keep this whole thing in one program.
I'd like this to be accessible throughout multiple parts of the program, so a regular call wouldn't suffice because I want the program to go back to wher it left off each time this is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very close.

Using `call :label` you can indeed call the same batch file as a separate process, as if it were a subscript. Using `goto :eof` you can return control to the main script, which will continue at the place it was.

It should also work when the subscript just ends, so, your code should actually work, except for the parentheses, which are invalid the way you use them. Just remove them and you script should work. It should echo:

```
This part
comes first.
```

Comment: you can even use more than one subroutine, if you end them with `goto :eof`

Comment: Yes of course. Every label can be a subroutine. And `goto :eof` is just a shortcut for terminating the script (either sub or main) without needing an extra label at the end of the file.